# How do I get year value form datepicker inline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using [bootstrapg datepicker](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) and I use the following js:

```
    $("#sandbox-container div").datepicker({
      format: "yyyy",
      viewMode: "years", 
      minViewMode: "years"
    });
    $(".datepicker").on("dp.change", function(e) {
      var myDate = $(this).val();
      console.log(myDate);
    });
```

And the html:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <label class="usp-label usp-label-category" for="usp-category">Time</label>
      <div id="sandbox-container"><div></div></div>
    <div>
  </div>
```

But I get no value or anything in console

**UPDATE**

Also tried:

```
    $("#sandbox-container div").datepicker({
      format: "yyyy",
      viewMode: "years", 
      minViewMode: "years"
    }).on("dp.change", function(e) {
      var myDate = $(this).val();
      console.log(myDate);
    });
```

Comment: Create a codepen/fiddler of your code

Comment: `$(".datepicker")` will not match any shown element..

Comment: @user2864740 yes, but the thing is that div with that class is auto created once datepicker is running

Comment: @user2864740 check I have also tried in a different way without using `.datepicker` class

Comment: Read about event delegation.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat where? I have read all the docs, I am doing something wrong tho and I am not sure where and how

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/event-delegation-with-jquery/ for starters

Comment: @AniketSahrawat please, I do know that. I am talking about the callback from the plugin I am using...

Comment: @AniketSahrawat these are the docs I am reading https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have resolved it:

**HTML**

```
    <div class="col">
        <label class="usp-label usp-label-category" for="usp-category">Time</label>
        <div id="sandbox-container"><div></div></div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
  $(function(){ 
    $('#sandbox-container div').datepicker({
      format: "yyyy",
      viewMode: "years", 
      minViewMode: "years"
    });
    $("#sandbox-container span").on("click", function(e) {
      $("#sandbox-container span").removeAttr("class", "selected_year");
      $(this).attr("class", "selected_year");
      var myDate = $(".selected_year").text();
      console.log(myDate);
    }); 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here requirement is to get the value of clicked year from a date picker that is showing year calendar.

Try :

```
$("#sandbox-container div.datepicker").datepicker({ 
 format: "yyyy", 
 viewMode: "years", 
 minViewMode: "years" 
 }).on("click", function(e) { 
 console.log(e.target.innerText); 
});
```

and change in html

```
  <div id="sandbox-container"><div class="datepicker"></div></div>
```

Comment: these are the docs I am reading https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html

Comment: changed the answer, now please check, if would be better if you could provide a jsfiddle etc

Comment: also check if the bootstrap js file is loading or not, you can also check datepicker() function in console by calling datepicker()